# Cancel ext js delayed task using "cancel" button

Tags: extjs

I have following method that has delayed task :

```
 exportDataToCSV: function () {
        var me = this,
            grid = this.option.up('grid');      

        var mask = Ext.widget('processingmessagebox', {
            target: grid,
            progressMessage: 'exporting',
            isProcessing: true,
            targetFunctions: {
                ConfirmCancelClick: me.stopExportingData
            }
        });
        mask.getViewModel().set({ ShowCancelBox: 'block' });
        var grdStore = grid.getStore();
        var grdProxy = grdStore.getProxy();
        exportData = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function () {

                me.printDataToCSV(grid, mask);

        });
        exportData.delay(2000);
    },
```

I am trying to stop or cancel this export data delay task using the following **but its not working** :

```
stopExportingData: function () {
    exportData.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Your code seems ok, there are any errors on the console? Your  `stopExportingData()` have the exportData scope?

Comment: @MatheusHatje it says exportData.cancel() is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@unhappy_vapor. 
Your code should work fine.

You can compare it with this fiddle which works well and see if maybe you are missing something: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31hr

Comment: Thanks.. I have verified, it is working. Now, I want to cancel the "exportdata" process without using delay.. any suggestions on how I can cancel this?